# Tkinter not open and save text file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, menu, tkinter

I am a newbie to python Tkinter.I have created a code which consists of a text box.I have additional File menu buttons : File,Open,Save,Exit
Problem: I cant able to save the contents of my textfile even after saving,I can't able to open my file when I click over the Open button.

Coding:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter
import Tkinter as tki
import tkFileDialog as th1
import tkFileDialog

class App(object):

    def __init__(self,root):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.root = root


    # create first Text label, widget and scrollbar
        self.lbl1 = tki.Label(self, text="Type")
        self.lbl1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)

        self.txt1 = tki.Text(self, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

        scrollb1 = tki.Scrollbar(txt_frm, command=self.txt1.yview)
        scrollb1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.txt1['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb1.set
def open_file():                                

        f=(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
            defaultextension = ".txt",
            filetypes=[("All Types", ".*")]))
        filename = f.name    
        return filename
def file_save():
    f = th1.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    filename = f.name
    return filename           
def Exit():
    exit()            

root = tki.Tk()
menubar=Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

filemenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=file_save)        
filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command = open_file)
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command = Exit)
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Please help me to fix my code!Answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do file operation, use `askopenfile`, `asksaveasfile` instead.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile

class App(object):

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.lbl1 = Label(root, text="Type")
        self.lbl1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txt1 = Text(root, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4, width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)

        scrollb1 = Scrollbar(root, command=self.txt1.yview)
        scrollb1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.txt1['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb1.set

    def open_file(self):
        f = askopenfile(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Types", ".*")])
        if not f:
            return
        self.txt1.delete(1.0, END)
        self.txt1.insert(END, f.read())
        f.close()

    def file_save(self):
        f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
        if not f:
            return
        f.write(self.txt1.get(1.0, END))
        f.close()
```

---

```
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
menubar = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=app.file_save)
filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=app.open_file)
filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: its not opening a file other than displaying the path in stdout.By the way what I meant for Save is,Whatever I type in the textbox then It should be saved.